# Issue with FirebaseDatabase and FirebaseFirestore Data Manupulate and Retriving data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My query is that I want to save some data in Firebase Realtime Database such that I will be able to call the data. Keeping in mind that users should be able to call the data even if they reinstall the app and each user will have a specific child.

I am trying to make an app where the user will enter or save data to firebase and display it on the App, however, the issue is that I am not having an Idea on how to retrieve the data from firebase.

The data which I am going to retrieve is the ItemName which I have saved inside

child(uid).child(ItemName);

each user will save their data with different `uid` inside different ItemName.

The thing is that how will I retrieve the ItemName for each user since the ItemName will be different so I will not have any data of the ItemName for a particular user. If I save the ItemName in SharedPreferences I will be able to retrieve it, however, if the user, formate their phone or uninstall and reinstall the app then SharedPreference data will be removed, SO HOW WILL I RETRIVE THE ITEMNAME data from Firebase for a particular user to display it.

MY CODE example:

```
String email= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
dbFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
userReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(itemName);
```

[image]

Is there any method or function which retrieve the data without specifying the Child pathname like default path if we redirect the path towards there like

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uid).child("");
```

something like that. or is there any other way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of I, please add it as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: The ItemName can be anything the above is just an example, it can be Car or anything. Since I have to arrange the data systematically, I am not having any idea how to retrieve it.

Comment: So you say that "Fried Chicken" is dynamic, right? Show us the content of that "Fried Chicken" and indicate the data that you want to get.

Comment: I want to retrieve the content present inside Fried Chicken, like quantity, size,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those values, without knowing the name of the intermediate node, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String friedChicken = ds.getKey();
            String foodType = ds.child("food_TYPE").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", friedChicken + "/" + foodType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
Fried Chicken / Non-Veg
```

In the same way I got the value of `food_TYPE`, you can also get the others.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am going to try the suggestion which you have posted. I will revert back as soon as I get the value. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing the result.

Comment: The line which you have shared is working, but still I didn't get it. I mean how is it working and able to call the child??? Can you please explain it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for your explanation. :)

Comment: Sure. The `onDataChange()` method fires only when the operation for getting the data from the database completes. Besides that, to get a child you always need to specify all nodes in the reference, see I have added a call to `.child("food_TYPE")` in order to get the value.

Comment: Okay, I got it, Thank you!!! I have another question, in case if I have more that one Child just like Fried Chicken, then, in that case, how will I get the data of the other Child, I would really appreciate it if you can resolve this one too. :)

Comment: There is nothing to do. If you add another child with the exact same structure, when using the code in my answer, you'll get two results. So you can use this code no matter how many children do you have.

Comment: Even if I have more than one Child just like Fried Chicken, how will I distinguish it in that case? Like this Item name is referring to Fried chicken this Item name is for the other Child?

Comment: Usually, we stick to one question at a time. But assuming you are a beginner so I'll tell you that `ds.getKey()` will return the name of the elements, for example, `Fried Chicken` and other if exist, while `ds.child("food_TYPE").getValue(String.class);` will always return the value of `food_TYPE` property. Note that this property should be named the same in all children.

Comment: So, we can add some condition after calling this method `ds.getKey()` to get the required Child which we want.

Comment: Yes, or you can add directly the name of that in a reference like this: `rootRef.child(uid).child("Fried Chicken")`

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uid).child("Fried Chicken");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String foodType = dataSnapshot.child("food_TYPE").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is I will not be knowing the ItemName which is Fried Chicken.. so my question is how will I retrieve the data without knowing it. and I have to save the data systematically at the database accordingly.

Comment: Lets say you clicked a button for fried chicken then in the OnClickListener() store that in a variable like String selected = "Fried Chicken"; and instead of "Fried Chicken" in the database reference put selected